# How to create an interface for a class that has templated functions?

Tags: c++, templates, dependency-injection, interface

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class A
{
  template<typename T>
  T readValue(std::string name) { 
    return member.readValue<T>(name);
  }
 private:
  MemberType member_;
}
```

I have another class that depends on it, and I need to inject that class with a mock version of this class. So I'm trying to create an interface for this class that I can depend on and implement with a mock object.

The problem is I can't create an interface with a templated function like this:

```
class IA
{
  template<typename T>
  virtual T readValue(std::string name) = 0;
}

class A : public IA
{
 public:
  template<typename T>
  virtual T readValue(std::string name)
  {
    return member_.readValue<T>(name);
  }
 private:
  MemberType member_;
}
```

How do I do this cleanly? All the existing answers for how to do this seem to require way too much for a simple interface extraction from a class.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense for a templated function to be virtual. Just go all the way with templates and instead of:

```
struct IA { /* ... */ };
struct A : IA { /* ... */ };

void foo(IA const&);
```

do

```
struct A { /* ... */ };

template <class IA>
void foo(IA const&);
```

Comment: How can I ensure that only classes that implement the interface are accepted as a template parameter?

Comment: @AlexisWinters Have a look at C++20 `concepts` for that. Pre-C++20, the usual practice was to document the desired interface and rely on compile-time duck-typing. That's what STL does anyway.

Comment: also: extensive use of `static_assert`

Comment: @MooingDuck how do you use `static_assert` to verify existence of a member function? SFINAE could be used.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili no, you definitely want to avoid SFINAE here. SFINAE is excellent at removing methods from a set of overloads, but if used in any other context, just results in confusing error messages. `static_assert` in classes and methods gives clear and readable compiler error messages.  `static_assert(std::is_same_v<char, decltype(parameter.readValue<char>("")), "parameter is missing a valid readValue member");`

Comment: @MooingDuck yes and no. Yes - `static_assert` is easier to read, but it is also not needed. Just use interface as if it has all the members you want. If it doesn't - compiler will slap you on the wrist. Actually, the slap will be exactly the same as with your code, since `static_assert` will not fire at all - there would be a compilation error before trying invoke it.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84c597b1a108b4bb. @SergeyA in complex cases, the slap on the wrist leads to confusing error messages. static_assert is the clearest, by far

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili the HUGE drawback of this approach is that all the functions which used to work with `A`, now need to become templates. In many cases, this is not acceptable.

Comment: @MooingDuck if you read your own error message, you will notice it does not mention static assert at all. `error: request for member 'readValue<char>' in 'std::declval<double>()', which is of non-class type 'double'` And I am not advocating for sfinae either, so not sure what your argument is.

Comment: @SergeyA OP was planning to re-write them to work with `IA` anyway. So, I don't think it's that big of a deal.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili nah, there is a million light years difference between changing a function which accepts an object of a class to function which accepts a pointer to a base class and making a non-template function a template. Sometimes the later is a non-starter.